# JQuery Multiple onload animation loops, bug with multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I have an issue on a site I am developing, a version of which can be seen at http://hg.ipagtest.com/ ! I am using JQuery and JCarosel for a slider feature on the bottom of the homepage and a piece of JQuery written by a former colleague of mien for a large image changer on the top of the page. 
The page loads as expected and the animations work as desired! Issues arise when clicking between tabs. When I click away from the tab and return to it, it seems as though the animation loop has been thrown out of whack! I have seen this problem in firefox 13 and in chrome 19 on windows 7, it does not occur with IE9 as far as I can see.

I replaced the code used on the top image changer with the code show here...
http://www.queness.com/post/152/simple-jquery-image-slide-show-with-semi-transparent-caption
I made this change on a dev. server which is not on line so I can't show you the link. This produced the exact same problem.

I realise that this is quite a specific problem but I am at a loss as to what to do next. Any help of pointers would be greatly appreciated

Neal

Answer (score 0):

small remark

replace:

```
.linkdiv {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 200px;  //
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;  //
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    top: 20px;  //
    width: 225px;  //
}
```

to:

```
.linkdiv {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 180px;  //
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 25px;  //
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    top: 0;  //
    width: 200px;  //
}
```